# File .htaccess not working with URL that has a dash and 2nd RewriteRule not applied

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a problem with `.htaccess` file, as I understand `RewriteRule` help to rewrite the URL. But when I try the following 2 cases it doesn't work.

#1 The first `RewriteRule` works but the second doesn't work

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?idcat=$1  [L] #working

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?idl=$1    [L] #not working
```

#2 The RewriteRule doesn't work with dash but works with slash and underscore.

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?idl=$1&iddis=$2  [L]  #not working

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)_([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?idl=$1&iddis=$2  [L]  #working

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?idl=$1&iddis=$2  [L]  #working
```

So how to fix these problems? Does anyone have any suggestions for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> #1 The first Rewriterule works but the second doesn't work
>
> ```
> RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?idcat=$1  [L] #working
>
> RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?idl=$1    [L] #not working
> ```

Because you are using the same pattern in both rules, the first rule always "wins" and the second rule is never triggered. This is essentially processed as follows (pseudo-code):

```
if (the URL matches the pattern "^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$") {
    rewrite the request to "index.php?idcat=<url>"
}
elseif (the URL matches the pattern "^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$") {
    rewrite the request to "index.php?idl=<url>"
}
```

As you can see, the second code block is never processed since the expressions are the same.

To put it another way, how would *you* determine whether a request of the form `/foo` should be rewritten to `index.php?idcat=foo` or to `index.php?idl=foo`? You can't rewrite the request to both.

In this particular case you could perhaps rewrite everything to `index.php?id=<url>` and let your script decide whether it should be `idcat` or `idl`. Otherwise, there needs to be something different about the two URLs (and consequently the *patterns* you are using to match the URLs) that allows you to determine how the URL should be rewritten.

> #2 The Rewriterule doesn't work with dash but works with slash and underscore.
>
> ```
> RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?idl=$1&iddis=$2  [L]  #not working
> RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)_([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?idl=$1&iddis=$2  [L]  #working
> ```

Both these rules have the same problem, depending on the URLs being requested. This is because the patterns/regex you are using are "ambiguous". Each of the two subpatterns (either side of the *delimiter*), that are used to match the `idl` and `iddis` values, contain the same character as the expected delimiter, `-` or `_`. However, in the 3rd rule (not shown), you are using a `/` as the delimiter, which does not occur in the surrounding subpatterns, so there is no ambiguity,

For example, how should (or you would expect) a URL of the form `/foo-bar-baz` to be matched by the first rule? Since the first subpattern uses the *greedy* quantifier `+`, it will capture `foo-bar` and `baz` and rewrite the request to `index.php?idl=foo-bar&iddis=baz`.

To avoid this "ambiguity" you need to make sure the delimiter between the subpatterns (ie. between the values for `idl` and `iddis`) is different to the characters used in the subpatterns (or at least one of the two subpatterns).

This can often be resolved by making the regex as specific as possible. ie. Match only the valid characters in `idl` and `iddis`.

To begin resolving this issue, you need to first identify the precise URLs you are trying to match, before implementing the rules to match them.

Comment: Woww thank you so much for the detailed explanation. I understood why it was wrong. Have a nice day bro :)